# Django: Use same view to process same form on two separate pages

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I may be overthinking this one or maybe not. I have a registration form that I want to use on the index page and as a standalone form. For some reason, the standalone form works just fine but the form on the index page gives me a 403 error when it's submitted. I will be using jQuery later on, but I need things to also work without JavaScript.

Renders Sign-Up form similar to Facebook homepage

```
# views.py snippet
class IndexPageTemplateView(TemplateView):  #  index page(http://localhost)
    template_name = 'fld/index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # prevent logged in users from accessing welcome page
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponse(reverse("member_homepage", args=some_args))
    else:
        return render_to_response(self.template_name)

# Account view

class AccountCreateView(CreateView):  # standalone(http://localhost/signup)
      model = Account
      form_class = CreateAccountForm
      template_name = 'fld2/account_form'
      success_url = 'thanks'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # prevent logged in users from seeing this form
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        # get the username of logged in user
        ...
        # redirect to homepage
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('some_args', args=(args,)))
    else:
        # display form to non members
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.get_form_class()})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        clean = form.cleaned_data
        form.instance = form.save()
        if form.instance:
           try:
               # send email
           except Account.DoesNotExist:
           ...
        return super(AccountCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I'm literally using the same exact forms with different action attributes. I've tried swapping the attribute values, using the same attribute values, and using no attribute values. I can't seem to access my view from the index page at all, even when I hard code it in I get the 403 error. Basically a visitor should be able to register on the homepage(like Facebook) or on the sign-up page( like Twitter). I'm thinking that I might have to use signals to make this work.

http://localhost/

```
 <!--index.html snippet-->
 <form action="{% url "create_account" %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="username" type="text" required>
    <input name="password" type="password" required>
    <input name="email" type="email" required>
    <input name="signup1" type="submit" value="Create account">
 </form>
```

http://localhost/signup

```
 <!--account_form.html-->
 <form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="username" type="text" required>
    <input name="password" type="password" required>
    <input name="email" type="email" required>       
    <input name="signup2" value="Create account" type="submit">
 </form>
```

main urls.py snippet

```
url(
    regex=r'^$',
    view=WelcomePageTemplateView.as_view(),
    name='index'
),
url(
    regex=r'^signup$',
    view=include('account.urls'),
    # name='signup'
),
url(
    regex=r'^(?P<slug>[\w]+)/settings/?',
    view=include('account.urls'),
)
```

account urls.py

```
url(
    regex=r'^$',
    view=AccountCreateView.as_view(),
    name="create_account"
),
```

Comment: Not related, but why do you render the form manually? Can't you just use something like `{{ form.as_table }}` `{{ form.as_table }}`?

Comment: I want more control over the presentation of the forms. as_p doesn't really provide me that. Also, I personally never use tables for non-tabular data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{% csrf_token %}` tag needs access to the request object in the template. You have used `render` in your `AccountCreateView` which includes the request by default, but in your `IndexPageTemplateView` you have used  your `render_to_response`, which does not.

The easiest way to fix the index view is to use `render` instead of `render_to_response`.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # prevent logged in users from accessing welcome page
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponse(reverse("member_homepage", args=some_args))
    else:
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

When you override class based views, it's usually a bad idea to override `get` and `post`, because you end up duplicating (or breaking) functionality. In your case, it would be better to call `super()` instead of writing your own code to return a response.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # prevent logged in users from accessing welcome page
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponse(reverse("member_homepage", args=some_args))
    else:
        return super(IndexPageTemplateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you. Just curious, isn't render_to_response just a layer of abstraction on-top of render?

Comment: `render` and `render_to_response` are both shortcuts. The difference is that `render` makes the request available in the template context, but `render_to_response` does not. The `render` shortcut was added later than `render_to_response`, but it has been available since way back in Django 1.3. The [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) shortcut is not recommended and is likely to be deprecated in future. If you always use `render` then you won't go wrong!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I have some refactoring to do.